# WordPress account not showing up on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

I have an issue with Stack Exchange's list of accounts. On my [list of accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/1419ca8d-5aed-47fd-b4c3-cb9f0c2e16e9?tab=accounts), my [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) account is not showing up.

Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong? (I have confirmed that the account is associated to my other accounts.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your WordPress account is listed now.

Combination of caching and some data bugs from a couple days ago.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for telling me.